# JSON.stringfy de objetos grandes com Angular 8

Tags: json, angular

estou iniciando uma aplicação com Angular 8 e tenho uma dúvida que está sendo complicada de resolver.

Existe uma maneira prática de transformar um objeto javascript em um JSON string definindo quais os atributos dele que eu quero passar?
Por exemplo: temo o seguinte Objeto

```
{  
   "id":null,
   "nome":"Pedro de Lara",
   "documento":"00000000000",
   "fone1":"1234",
   "municipio":{  
      "id":4861,
      "nome":"Carlos Barbosa",
   }
}
```

Gostaria que essa função, automaticamente, transformasse o município para que ficasse apenas com o id, por exemplo:

```
{  
   "id":null,
   "nome":"Pedro de Lara",
   "documento":"00000000000",
   "fone1":"1234",
   "municipio":{  
      "id":4861
   }
}
```

Esse exemplo é um pequeno objeto, mas o que eu preciso é fazer isso com objetos "filhos" maiores.

Desculpem se a pergunta é muito boba, sou novo no assunto e não achei nenhuma opção que me convença a ser a melhor.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenho duas dicas, você pode deletar usando a propriedade delete do javascript:

> delete object.municipio.nome;

ou usando a lib lodash:

> $ yarn add lodash

```
import _ from lodash;


object.municipio =_.omit(object.municipio, ['nome']);
```

[_.omit-lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#omit)

A respeito do tamanhos dos objetos filhos(nested objects), não existe um tamanho limite para uma String no Javascript, o problema é se você for enviar essa String em alguma requisição, ou se o objeto tiver uma estrutura muito complexa; se ele for um objeto circular você vai precisar converter para JSON antes de transformar em String.

Comment: Bom dia, então, percebi que eu teria esse problema circular, foi ai que resolvi começar a procurar alternativas. eu precisaria transformar esse objeto para JSON, seria utilizando o JSON.parce?

Comment: Não, manualmente, é como se você pegasse desse objeto circular só o que você quisesse. Essa lib lodash tem o _.pick, ele é ao contrário do _.omit, com esse método você pega só o que você quer de um objeto. Dá uma olhada aqui: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso, acredito que a melhor maneira é trabalhar com um model. Você cria um novo arquivo chamado pessoa.model.ts com o seguinte código:

```
export class Municipio{
  id: number;
}


export class User {
  id: number;
  nome: string;
documento: number;
fone1: string;
municipio: Municipio = new Municipio();

  constructor(json: any) {
    this.id = json.id;
    this.nome = json.nome;
    this.documento = json.documento;
    this.fone1 = json.fone1;
    this.municipio.id = json.municipio.id;
  }
}
```

e no seu código principal, importa o model:

```
import { User } from "./pessoa.model.ts";
```

e no código, ao criar um novo User utilizando esse model, ele irá pegar apenas o id do município:

```
var pessoa = new User({"id":null, "nome":"Pedro de Lara", "documento":"00000000000", "fone1":"1234", "municipio":{"id":4861, "nome":"Carlos Barbosa"}});
```

Caso queira ver funcionando, [pode ir neste link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yepixm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser.model.ts).